# Why does my material seem 'pixelated'?

Tags: rendering, materials

I'm new to Blender. I did the donut and cup (blender guru). When I render, the glass cup is pixelated. Why is that? I have a Nvidia Quadro RTX 3000 graphic card. Also, the menu on the bottom right hand side i.e. texture, light, render etc., it's all huge now. I don't know what happened.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). It's not very clear from your screenshot, could you add an mage of your whole Blender window?

Answer (score 0):

Glass cup not pixelated, but a lot of noise, which caused by small amount of samples.

It can be reduced in viewport with OptiX viewport denoiser in Render tab (OptiX avaible only on RTX cards):

[image: ptiX viewport denoiser]

at render with  View layer denoising:

[image: View layer denoising]

or after render with Intel Open Image Denoiser node in Compositor (Denoising Data should be checked in View Layer):

[image: Intel Open Image Denoiser node in Compositor]

And the last, the scale of blender layouts could be customized by holding `Ctrl + Middle mouse button pressed with moving mouse Up and Down`

Comment: Thank you kindly. Is my laptop ok? I'm thinking of switching... It seems GeForce RTX 2060-2080 are better than Quadro RTX 3000. Ant thoughts??

Comment: For laptop is more then OK. But 2080 up to 30% better..